# Attachment page custom title?

Tags: attachments

Look what I want to do... I want to edit < title > < /title > from < head > < /head > on attachment page.

Right now I have like this:  **POST PARENT TITLE (no - or | here ) IMAGE TITLE - MY BLOG TITLE**

I want to show like this **IMAGE TITLE | MY BLOG TITLE**

How can I do this? I really want to do it. in ALl in one seo pack is not this option..

Regards!

Comment: you can use AIO wordpress plugin like me with tutorial right [here](http://olengkblogs.blogspot.com/2012/05/memperbaiki-struktur-title-attachment.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `attachment.php` is the template for attachment pages. So you can edit existing one or create new if you have none.

You can also create different templates for different [mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME): http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Edit:

Sorry, in a case you want to change HTML page title, you may want to use [`is_attachment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_attachment) in `header.php` of your theme.

Something like this:

```
<title><?php if( is_attachment() ) { ... } else { ... };?></title>
```

Comment: Is not good.. i want title of the page in The PAGE TAB not in as post title.. that i can do it.

Comment: @user10416 I've updated my answer

Comment: Something like <title><?php if( is_attachment() ?> <?php the_title(); ?> <?php else ?> <?php wp_title(); ?> <?php endif; ?></title>

Comment: @user10416 :-) feel free to add your own answer and accept it

Comment: it's not good my answer...

Comment: @user10416 Does your theme's `header.php` already contain some conditions for title? How your theme prints HTML page title now?

Comment: <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title> but i use All in one seo pack

Comment: Try to change it to `<title><?php if( is_attachment() ) { the_title(); } else { wp_title(); } ?></title>`.

Comment: Now on image attachment i get  POST TITLE - IMAGE TITLE - BLOG TITLE..... i think is something from wp-includes but i dont know from where..

Comment: @user10416 Now I believe that AllInOne SEO messes something up. Can you try to turn it off for a while?